# Why would these two resistors make a parallel connection?

Tags: resistors, thevenin

[image: Circuit Given on the Left; My Interpretation on the Right]

The circuit on the left is the one that is given and the circuit on the right is the way that I visualize the circuit. Could someone explain why the equivalent resistance would be 5kΩ?

Comment: To find the Thévenin-equivalent resistance you need to "turn off" the 5V source, what would happen then?

Comment: You're brilliant. Thank you so much. I can't believe I was overlooking that

Comment: The two circuits are the same, so you are definitely thinking about it correctly. The two resistors are not in parallel, but if you want to calculate the Thevenin equivalent, then you will end up with the parallel value. Also, for AC analysis both +5V and GND are considered to be ground. So for AC analysis purposes, they ARE parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given in the comment is valid and I wanted to add a quick illustration to show the flow. When you redraw the original circuit with the 5-V source in, you can determine the open-circuit voltage \$V_{th}\$ by identifying a resistive divider:

[image]

Then, you want to determine the output resistance of this divider. To do so, turn the source off to 0 V and replace it by a wire. Then "look" at the resistance seen across \$R_2\$. This is the output resistance you want and it is simply the parallel combination of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. With these elements in hand, you can form a simple equivalent Thévenin generator as shown in the low side of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

The two resistors are definitely not in parallel. You redrew the circuit correctly, so I think your understanding is accurate.

If I try to think of how they might be in parallel, or what additional context could justify the parallel idea, I come up with two ideas.

First, there is the Thevenin equivalent. I don't know if you have learned it yet. But if you convert a circuit to its Thevenin equivalent, you use the open circuit voltage (VOC) and the short circuit current (ISC) to calculate Req. Then the circuit is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQdmJr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From the perspective of the reference node, these two circuits are identical. Note that Req is just the parallel resistance of R1 and R2.

The other context would be in AC analysis. For AC analysis, you replace all fixed DC voltages with GND. So you can see that if +5V is replaced with GND, then the two resistors really would be in parallel.

So I am guessing that you encountered the statement about them being in parallel in one of these two contexts.